# How to change Google Calendar embed event color?

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I create a google calendar and create events by Google Client Libarary for PHP. When creating this, I set "colorId" for event (pink color). But when I embed Google calendar in my website, events only show the blue color (despite I saw this event has pink color in my Google calendar).

This is the example that I want to make like this : http://www.vanderbilt.edu/psychological_sciences/reservation-calendar.php

[image]

Anyone can give me a solution for that, thanks very much !!!

Comment: I don't think you can change the color of the events. After lot of research I found this link https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/3FTWtCu5gmU

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

What They have done is created a separate calendar for each room, color coded each of those calendars, and then combined them all for display on the embedded calendar.  This is obvious by their note to "Click on pull-down menu at top right of calendar to filter by room." - that dropdown is used in Google Calendar to filter which calendar(s) should be displayed.