# Create Calendar Events to Calendars identified in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

**I am very new and inexperienced with Apps Script. /
I am working on a facilities request system for our high school.  Coaches, teachers, etc, can fill out a form to request/reserve practices or events for multiple locations around our campus. I am trying to create Google Calendar events from Google Sheets where the calendar name is identified by the location chosen in the Google Form/Sheet (Column D). For example, the basketball coach would request the Main Gym for a date and time (duration) and a calendar event would be created on the Main Gym calendar.  There are multiple calendars that are already created and owned by me.
I have watched several YouTube videos and tried some sample scripts but none help with exactly what I need.  Any help would be appreciated.

I think I have several errors in the code.  [Here is a copy of the spreadsheet.][1]

```
        function createCalendarEvent() {
  let spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let request=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  request.splice(0,1);
  let getOwnedCalendarsByName=Spreadsheet.getDataRange(4);
  let athleticsCalendar=CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName()
  
  

 request.forEach(function(entry){
 
 athleticsCalendar.creat(entry[2],entry[6],entry[8]);
  });

}


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zdevdFr8R0xmQNoO3wveLgty189PrFVTlTe-HpJUfGE/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the code I am using right now.  I am getting the following errors:

12:07:17 PM Error   
ReferenceError: Title is not defined
createEvent @ Code.gs:32
selectCalendarID    @ Code.gs:26



    var calendarId = " ";
var typeId = 4; //define column which data to be use to select calendar id (in your case, "location" column 4)
var title = 3
var startDtId = 7;
var endDtId = 9;
 
function selectCalendarID() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var lr = rows.getLastRow();
 

  var startDt = sheet.getRange(lr, startDtId, 1, 1).getValue();
  var endDt = sheet.getRange(lr, endDtId, 1, 1).getValue();
  var type = sheet.getRange(lr, typeId, 1, 1).getValue();
    //select calendar id based on schedule type
    if(type == "Aux Gym" || type == "OL 2") {
    calendarId = "c_cvla3g52fqbd4l20rvhk7er8tg@group.calendar.google.com"; 
  } else if (type == "Main Soccer Field" || type == "BK 2") {
    calendarId = "c_7jau68ofbhbeivnomh232dbelg@group.calendar.google.com"; 
  } else if (type == "GT 1" || type == "GT 2") {
    calendarId = "calId3@group.calendar.google.com";
  }
  createEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt);
}
 
 
function createEvent(calendarId, title, startDt, endDt) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var title = new Title(title);
  var start = new Date(startDtId);
  var end = new Date(endDtId);
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1);
  var type = type;
  var event = cal.createEvent(title,start, end, {
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work but I didn't test it. Fo your approach to work, you will need to get the calendar by ID then you will be able to create the event under that calendar.

First, you will need to remove the header row:

```
  request.slide(1)
```

second, you can create variables that hold the calendar id so you can use them later in the loop:

```
  let aux_gym_calendar_id = ""
  let main_soccer_field_calendar_id = ""
  ...
```

Third, the `switch` statement to create the event under the designated calendar. You should use `getCalendarById` instead of `getOwnedCalendarsByName` since `getCalendarById` returns an instance of the calendar which you can use to create the event.

```
  switch (calendarsName) {
    case "Aux Gym":
     cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(aux_gym_calendar_id)
     cal.createEvent(entry[2], entry[6], entry[8])
     break;
    case "Main Soccer Field":
     cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(main_soccer_field_id)
     cal.createEvent(entry[2], entry[6], entry[8])
  }
```

Here is the full code:

```
 function createCalendarEvent() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let request = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  //remove header row
  request = request.slice(1)

  let cal = ""
 //Declare and init calendar id variables
  let aux_gym_calendar_id = ""
  let main_soccer_field_id = ""

  request.forEach(function (entry) {
   //get the calendar name
   let calendarsName = entry[3];

  //create event on selected calendar
  switch (calendarsName) {
    case "Aux Gym":
     cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(aux_gym_calendar_id)
     cal.createEvent(entry[2], entry[6], entry[8])
     break;
    case "Main Soccer Field":
     cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(main_soccer_field_id)
     cal.createEvent(entry[2], entry[6], entry[8])
  }
  });

  }
```

Resources: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getOwnedCalendarById(String)

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.  I ran your code and got this error:9:00:49 AM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:21
createCalendarEvent @ Code.gs:13

Answer (score 0):

Just to share what im doing for selecting multiple calendar ids. After a lot of searching (Im not a programmer my self), I found out that using if can get the job done too.

```
var calendarId = " ";
var typeId = 2; //define column which data to be use to select calendar id (in your case, "location" column 4)
var startDtId = 4;
var endDtId = 5;
```

Then, just insert if else statement like this

```
function selectCalendarID() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var lr = rows.getLastRow();

  var startDt = sheet.getRange(lr, startDtId, 1, 1).getValue();
  var endDt = sheet.getRange(lr, endDtId, 1, 1).getValue();
  var type = sheet.getRange(lr, typeId, 1, 1).getValue();
    //select calendar id based on schedule type
    if(type == "OL 1" || type == "OL 2") {
    calendarId = "calId1@group.calendar.google.com"; 
  } else if (type == "BK 1" || type == "BK 2") {
    calendarId = "calId2@group.calendar.google.com"; 
  } else if (type == "GT 1" || type == "GT 2") {
    calendarId = "calId3@group.calendar.google.com";
  }
  createAllDayEvent(calendarId,startDt,endDt);
}
}

function createAllDayEvent(calendarId, startDt, endDt) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var start = new Date(startDt);
  var end = new Date(endDt);
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1);
  var type = type;
  var event = cal.createAllDayEvent(start, end, {
    }); 
}
```

Hope this help

*P/S
Got an idea from here*
[How to change Google Calendar embed event color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830733/how-to-change-google-calendar-embed-event-color)
and here https://www.considerednormal.com/2014/04/adding-a-google-calendar-event-using-google-forms/

Comment: @amein--Thank you so much.  Your code has gotten me closer than any other.  Mine need to be single timed events (beginning time and ending time) not all day events.  Do you have any suggestions on making that change.  And also, I am having trouble with the title of the event picking up what is in the third column.

Comment: Change to 'createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)' instead. For title column, just define on which column on the spreadsheet. Could you update your code with latest one?

Comment: I think I added my current code to my original comment.